# how to cut columns without NaN values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have separate this dataframe

```
  cod contact1 contact2 texto
0   a   NaN 1   text1
1   b   2   NaN text2
2   c   3   NaN text3
3   d   NaN 4   text4
4   e   5   NaN text5
```

in all text for contact1

```
   cod contact1 texto
1   b   2   text2
2   c   3   text3
4   e   5   text5
```

and texts for contact2

```
  cod contact2  texto
0   a   1   text1
3   d   4   text4
```

need help?

Answer (score 0):

```py
df1 = df[df["contact1"].notna()].drop(columns="contact2")
df2 = df[df["contact2"].notna()].drop(columns="contact1")

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
  cod  contact1  texto
1   b       2.0  text2
2   c       3.0  text3
4   e       5.0  text5

  cod  contact2  texto
0   a       1.0  text1
3   d       4.0  text4
```